# Solution for data conversion

Tags: c++

today I trying to design a timestamping for a message that i send and the code that i use in the function is below:

```
void MainWindow::buttonClickHandler()
{
    QString qs;
    qs=ui->lineEdit->text();
    std::string m_text=qs.toStdString();
    //std::string m_text = ui->lineEdit->text();
        // Customized message
    long long startTime = System::currentTimeMillis();    
    try{
            std::auto_ptr<TextMessage> message(m_IfacomMessageBroker->getSession()->createTextMessage(m_text));
            //message->setCMSTimestamp(System::currentTimeMillis());

            //m_IfacomMessageBroker->sendMessage(message);
             m_IfacomMessageBroker->sendMessage("test");
            long long ltest = m_IfacomAmqProducer->getSenderTimestamp(message);
            QDateTime *dt = new QDateTime();
            dt->setMSecsSinceEpoch(ltest);
            QString qtstring1 = dt->toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz");
        } catch (CMSException& e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }

        long long endTime = System::currentTimeMillis();
        double totalTime = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
   m_IfacomMessageBroker->close();
}
```

When I try to build the solution, I have this error:

```
Error   12  error C2664: 'IfacomAmqSender::getSenderTimestamp' : cannot convert   parameter 1 from 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' to 'const cms::Message *'   C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Activemq\ReleaseVersions\GUI-CMS-SENDER\mainwindow.cpp   105 1   GUI-CMS-SENDER
```

but the strange thing is that I use this function without problem in another .cpp file!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `m_IfacomAmqProducer->getSenderTimestamp(message.get())`.